# Java mail API - From email id defaults to email id used for authentication

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail API for sending emails from my application. Below is the code snippet for the session creation:

```
final String username = "<email id of gmail business account>";
final String password = "<password of the gmail business account>";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS

Session session = 
   Session.getInstance(
        props,
        new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
```

Below is the code snippet for setting the "From":

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(adminUserEmailId, adminUserName));
```

I'm using the email id of the admin user in the application for setting the "From". But when the email is sent (I sent one to my gmail id), the name comes right but I see the "From email id" set as the email id of the gmail business account (instead of the email id I set for "From"). Can someone please throw some light on how to solve this?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) describes how to send email with a different From address than you used to login.